# How to increase poolsize in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Getting TimeoutError in sqlalchemy when using with pyramid

```
TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30

extension = ZopeTransactionExtension()
session = sessionmaker(extension=extension, expire_on_commit=False)
DBSession = scoped_session(session)
Base = declarative_base()
```

I am using the above connection procedure to run few cronjobs, some times i hit timeout error.
I am closing the session after completion of task.

The other way to get rid of above error is increasing pool_size, but how to do in pyramid.

Comment: Is it something like this
 sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/mydb?pool_size=20

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
After looking at the code
[https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/**init**.py#L376](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py#L376)

```
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/your_db
sqlalchemy.pool_size = 10
sqlalchemy.max_overflow = 15
```